# Can a listview handle too many items?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview containing items from an external database in sql,but i was wondering if i added for example a 100 million item to that listview:

1.Will the listview lag when scrolling for example?

2.Will it also take time loading?

I will appreciate any help!

Filtering listview code:

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String text = etSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                myAppAdapter.filter(text);
            }
        });
```

filter:

```
public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            itemArrayList.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                itemArrayList.addAll(arraylist);

            } else {
                for (ClassListItems st : arraylist) {
                    if (st.getProname().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                        itemArrayList.add(st);
                    }

                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different implementations of list view and what is even more important - adapters.

First of all, you at least should consider `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

[Official documentation on using RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) gives us this information in the first sentence (emphasis is mine):

> If your app needs to display a scrolling list of elements based on **large data sets** (or data that frequently changes), you should use RecyclerView as described on this page.

Furthermore, there are advanced adapters like [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) that uses [powerful DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) tool that is built into this adapter (also available separately) to determine differences between items displayed and items submitted display. It calculates differences and requests to redraw or remove only those items that actually need this, removing any redundant work on re-drawing already drawn layout.

So "short" answer to this question will be:

1. If we are talking about 100 million items - Android most likely won't be able to hold that in memory and your application will crash with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. But yes, these lists can handle big amount of data with no problems, if you implement your part correctly;
2. Most probably it will take time to load data from a DB rather than load from memory and draw on the screen. These views display only that amount of data that fits on the screen. If you have 10,000 elements but only 5 the screen can hold only 5 then the number of drawn elements will be at most 7 (+1 off-screen on each side to scroll smoothly). That is if you use views provided by from Android SDK. Custom views can draw anything.

Generally, big amounts of data are not a problem unless they get very big. If they do - loading from permanent storage is a solution. I've experience using Realm ([iOS](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)/[Android](https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/)) database in applications that made it's way to Play Market and App Store. It works very fast and it does not care about the amounts of data you have. It makes it easy to display very big amounts of data.

Comment: So,can i make a search edit text that only displays the data searched in the list view?
if yes, i already made a search edittext that filters the listview but how can i make the list empty at first until i provide some text in the search view?!

And will that increase the listview's performance?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The list view can be empty in case the search view is empty. Usually, you attach a text watcher that will be called on every character change. If the resulting string is empty - do not query DB, make list empty. I doubt that it will increase the list view performance. What will increase is [debounce](https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/debounce-and-throttle-in-real-life-scenarios-1cc7e2e38c68) on your search view to postpone data queries until user types in most or all of the search string.

Comment: Yes, i am using a text watcher.
I posted my code and i would love to see an example of making the lisview empty at first!

Comment: Sorry, but this should be a different question.

Comment: Okay, will ask that in a different question soon.
Anyways thanks for your answer it helped a lot,And of course i will accept it!